# Assertions for asynchronous behaviour

Tags: rspec

In GOOS[1] they use an assertion called assertEventually which samples 
the system for a success state until a certain timeout has elapsed. This 
allows you to synchronise the tests with asynchronous code.

Do we have an equivalent of that in the Ruby / RSpec world already? I 
know capybara has wait_until { } but that's fairly rudimentary - the 
failure message isn't very helpful. Is there anything else already out 
there?

[1] http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. "wait_for" is a method Brian Takita and I originally wrote for
use in Selenium tests, then IIRC it made it into the Selenium gem and
now lots of libraries use it (or their own version -- I make no patent
claim on polling :-)). The wait_for I remember allowed you to
customize the failure message. Let me go see if it's on GitHub or
anything...

Ah, here's one:
https://github.com/pivotal/selenium/blob/master/lib/selenium/wait_for.rb

Answer (score 1):

Add this function to the code

```
def wait_for
  timeout = 3
  start = Time.now
  x = yield
  until x
    if Time.now - start > timeout
      raise "Wait to long here. Timeout #{timeout} sec"
    end
    sleep(0.1)
    x = yield
  end
end
```

And then use each time, when you need to wait for something async:

```
  client.check_mail
  wait_for do
    !client.envelope.nil?
  end
  expect(client.envelope.message['sender']).to eq 'Subzero'
```

In example envelope filled with data by async call